# Panic at the Disco's "Death of a Bachelor" influences

Tags: style, influence

I recently heard Panic at the Disco's new song ["Death of a Bachelor"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nG38N8FcWxo) that is set to release on their upcoming album. The song immediately struck me as lyrically and stylistically different from their past songs (even the most recent ones).

Is the vocal style and range influenced by Frank Sinatra in this song? I want to say even the lyrics are leaning toward something Sinatra would write (in the verses at least). There are even jazz horns in the background that add to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this song is a 100th birthday tribute to Frank Sinatra, as confirmed by the band's Instagram post:

> Frank Sinatra turns 100 this year. I attach his music to so many memories: Opening presents on Christmas day, my grandparents teaching the rest of the family to swing dance, watching “Who Framed Roger Rabbit” with my siblings (Sinatra makes a cameo in the form of a cartoon sword singing “Witchcraft”). His music has been a major player in the soundtrack of my life. So it’s only right that I return the favor and/or pay it forward.
>   https://instagram.com/p/7F-DAeiYV6/